# MVC Database First - Populating Dropdownlistfor text and values from DB

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, entity-framework-4

and totally confused now .
i am using Database First approach for developing an application

my code have models generated by ER from Table/DB
and i have created modelview for each respective models.

i have to show some "applications" name  in Dropdownlist via DB 
and user have to insert respective "environment" name  using a textbox and dropdown, auto populated on  UI  .

i have 2 viewmodel class "app_details and env_details:.

app_details have public properties 
appID(identity), Appname

and env_details have 
appID (fk), Envid(identity),envname.

i have done with adding the application name and have a SP to getappname and id

i am confused where to add 
public IEnumerable Appdetail { get; set; }
without getting model state not valid

i want to bind my model to view. how to approach PLS

Comment: i have 2 Model app {appid , appname} and env{envid,appid,envname}.. i created a modelview" appMV {appid[key], appname, selectlist }" now a fucntion return appMV list initializing appID and appname only, from this list i initilized i selectlist in controller and pass modelview obj to myview , where i have to enter enviroment details respective to app id , i am getting the dropdown list but on selecting the dropdown and after filling  the environment details iam getting model state not valid and appid null in controller . [post] using viewmodle app object in controller.

Comment: Your need to show the code you have tried in the question and indicated what error your getting where and when (not in comments) We cannot guess what mistakes you have made.

Answer (score 0):

Simply You can create a Select list with the appropriate item key and value and Bind that with drop down by passing to helper.